# Cannot flash Android IoT image for Pico Pro Maker Kit

Tags: rom-flashing

I got a Pico Pro Maker kit and use a Windows 10 PC. I followed the flashing instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html). Device Manager detects the kit this way: [image: Android ADB interface]

The device is in fastboot mode, but when I execute the flash-all script, an error message is returned (cannot load 'u-boot.imx'):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
```

(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Minden jog fenntartva.

C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices

List of devices attached

C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>fastboot devices

000000e5f4439b02 fastboot

C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>C:\F_Android_Things_NXPPico\flash-all.bat

error: cannot load 'u-boot.imx'

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came trough. Looked int flash-all.bat script which says:

> The fastboot executable must be in your path to run this script

I copied all the Android Thing image, generated by the [AndroidThingsConsole](https://partner.android.com/things/console/) into the C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\ subdir, and run the script flash-all.bat again.
Result is here:

C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>flash-all.bat

target reported max download size of 209715200 bytes

sending 'bootloader' (479 KB)...

OKAY [  0.017s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.397s]
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.009s]

finished. total time: 0.457s

< waiting for any device >

target reported max download size of 209715200 bytes

sending 'gpt' (33 KB)...
OKAY [  0.006s]
writing 'gpt'...
OKAY [ 28.856s]

rebooting into bootloader...

OKAY [  0.006s]

finished. total time: 28.876s

target reported max download size of 209715200 bytes

Creating filesystem with parameters:

```
Size: 2009071616
Block size: 4096
Blocks per group: 32768
Inodes per group: 8176
Inode size: 256
Journal blocks: 7664
Label:
Blocks: 490496
Block groups: 15
Reserved block group size: 119
```

Created filesystem with 11/122640 inodes and 16088/490496 blocks

sending 'boot_a' (32768 KB)...

OKAY [  0.886s]
writing 'boot_a'...
OKAY [  1.222s]
sending 'boot_b' (32768 KB)...
OKAY [  0.883s]
writing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  1.235s]
erasing 'system_a'...
OKAY [  7.114s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 1/2 (203704 KB)...
OKAY [  5.909s]
writing 'system_a' 1/2...
OKAY [  8.516s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 2/2 (204764 KB)...
OKAY [  6.189s]
writing 'system_a' 2/2...
OKAY [ 11.602s]
erasing 'system_b'...
OKAY [  6.999s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 1/2 (203704 KB)...
OKAY [  5.993s]
writing 'system_b' 1/2...
OKAY [  8.500s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 2/2 (204764 KB)...
OKAY [  5.818s]
writing 'system_b' 2/2...
OKAY [ 11.603s]
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [ 26.163s]
sending 'userdata' (33356 KB)...
OKAY [  0.903s]
writing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.252s]
Setting current slot to 'a'...
OKAY [  0.030s]
finished. total time: 110.864s
target reported max download size of 209715200 bytes
sending 'gapps_a' (72040 KB)...
OKAY [  1.929s]
writing 'gapps_a'...
OKAY [  2.570s]
sending 'gapps_b' (72040 KB)...
OKAY [  1.938s]
writing 'gapps_b'...
OKAY [  2.467s]
finished. total time: 8.917s
target reported max download size of 209715200 bytes
sending 'oem_a' (1096 KB)...
OKAY [  0.036s]
writing 'oem_a'...
OKAY [  0.139s]
sending 'oem_b' (1096 KB)...
OKAY [  0.036s]
writing 'oem_b'...
OKAY [  0.123s]
finished. total time: 0.344s

Successfully flashed your imx7d.
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.001s

C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>